# Copying files using Google drive REST APIs

Tags: google-drive-api

Using Google drive's REST APIs, is it possible to copy a file from one folder to another? I can see a webservice for move but not for copy. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use [Files.copy()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy). If you want to copy a file to different folder, put destination folder id to 'parents[]' in request body. There are sample codes for various languages you can try in the documentation.

Comment: No, it won't. If you really want to copy folder, you should make a new folder and copy all the children of original folder to destination folder.